# Ubuntu 22.04 issues with mouse settings

Tags: mouse

From couple of days I have the latest Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm very happy - but first time I have issues with my bt mouse (Logitech MX Master)
When I connect my mouse via bluetooth and set pointer speed and flat type - everything is fine, but everytime when I disconnect mouse and reconnect I loose mouse settings and  have to set pointer speed manually.
I'm using KDE and have a question - why after reconnect my mouse Ubuntu don't launch saved mouse configuration ?
I tried even set configuration with xinput but with no effect.
Is is possible to install some alternative app for ubuntu which will control my mouse settings ?

Comment: Check out `solaar`. It's in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: solaar works only with unifying receiver but it's about bluetooth connection,

Comment: Doesn't the Logitech MX Master work with unifying dongle also?

Comment: yes this mx master works with unifying as well, but the issue is both with bt and unifying.
when I customize settings for my mouse for example disable acceleration and speed - when I disconnect and reconnect my mouse - settings are lost and I'm at default settings. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Where are you customizing settings for the mouse... in Solaar, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into this bug:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435113

Which has now been fixed in KDE. The workaround until this fix filters down into distros is to run `kcminit kcm_mouse` manually after plugging in / connecting the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference.](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435113#c88).

The gist of it is that there's currently a bug where `kcminit mouse` is being called instead of `kcminit kcm_mouse`.

With this in mind, we can fix this by moving `/usr/bin/kcminit` to `/usr/bin/kcminit.real`, and then creating a shell script called `/usr/bin/kcminit` and add a shim into it.

So how do we go around to do that?

1. Move the original `kcminit` -> `sudo mv /usr/bin/kcminit /usr/bin/kcminit.real`
2. Create the shim -> `sudo touch /usr/bin/kcminit && chmod +x /usr/bin/kcminit`
3. Add this to the shim:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$*" == "mouse" ]]; then
  exec /usr/bin/kcminit.real kcm_mouse
else
  exec /usr/bin/kcminit.real "$@"
fi
```

You can test this by unplugging your mouse and plugging it back.